# Relative Date Value (THIS WEEK,NEXT WEEK,LAST WEEK)

Tags: date, list-view, filters, locale

I have below filter in List view for my custom object and client's locale is US English.

> Scheduled Date equals THIS WEEK

List view retrieves all records with scheduled date from Sunday to Saturday.

Client wants the THIS WEEK  filter start from Monday to Sunday.

> Same issue with Scheduled Date equals NEXT WEEK and Scheduled Date
>   equals LAST WEEK

From this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_dates.htm&type=0).UK English starts from Monday and ends Sunday.We don't want to change Client Locale to UK English.

Any other ways to achieve this without manually editing the filter dates ?

Comment: This has been released now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That functionality does not exist, but Salesforce is aware that people want it. Based on comments (19 days ago at the time of this post) by the SF product team, this feature may see its way into the Lightning Experience. You can vote on the idea [here.](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrjUAAS)

Please note that while the title mentions weeks within reporting, custom work weeks have been mentioned in other contexts in some of the ideas that have been merged into this one.

Answer (score 0):

From this [link](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000CnmgAAC), I found a workaround for this issue.

The only way to change the way "This Week" is used would be to create a custom formula Date field that acts as an 'offset' for the real Date field.  For example, if you wanted to use "CreatedDate This Week", but the week should start on Monday instead of Sunday, you could create a custom formula Date field with a formula of:

CreatedDate - 1

This custom formula field will always be 1 day behind the CreatedDate, so a CreatedDate of Sunday, would have a Saturday custom Date (and be included in the previous week).

Answer (score -1):

The post was updated:
There is an appExchange app Ascendix Search that supports filtering by relative dates and has various date/datetime operators.

Ascendix Search supports relative date filtering including 'The next/the last X Days/Weeks/Months. You can also set the last 7 days filter to achieve what you need.

https://ascendix.com/ascendix-search/

Disclosure: I work for Ascendix.

Comment: Hi please remember if you have any affiliations with a supplier then it needs to be clear in the answer, also a link with this brief a description does not really supply an answer. see [answer]

Comment: Dave, thank you for your comments. I clarified my comment.